# Core Graphics screenshot without hidden items

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm using Core Graphics to take a screenshot of my *UIView*, and then place it on top of that View (so I can animate it later):

```
// Get the screen shot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(target.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[target.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageView * ss = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

// Add it to the View
[overlay addSubview:ss];
[target addSubview:overlay];
```

The problem: my UIView `target` has some invisible items on it (I tried both `alpha = 0` and `hidden = YES` on them).  These invisible items are appearing in the screenshot.

How can I take a screenshot without these invisible items appearing?

**UPDATE:**  I tried using the code in [Technical Q&A QA1703: Screen Capture in UIKit Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html), which also present the same issue.

**UPDATE #2:**  It appears that the issue occurs with views that have CATransform3D applied.  In another parent view that has 3D subviews, when this screenshot is taken the 3D effect is removed from the views and they appear flat (2D).

Comment: Hidden items are being displayed, even if the alpha is zero? That's really strange.

Comment: What kind of views are those? I just did a simple test with some `UIViews` that had `alpha` set to `0.0` and it worked just fine (they were hidden in the screenshot).

Comment: @omz - they are UIViews with a UILabel.  They are animated by Core Data at a different time, so it is possible that they may have `CATransform`s applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was not just that they were hidden, but CATransform3D is applied.

The Stack Overflow question ["renderInContext:" and CATransform3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530250/renderincontext-and-catransform3d) has more info, but the gist is:

> QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not rendered, nor are layers that specify backgroundFilters, filters, compositingFilter, or a mask values.

(from [the CALayer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

If your app is not going to the app store you can use the undocumented `UIGetScreenImage` API:

```
// Define at top of implementation file
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);

...

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
  // Capture screen here...
  CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
  CGImageRelease(screen);

  // Save the captured image to photo album
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
```

(from [John Muchow](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html))

However, use of this API will make your app not get approved.

I have been unable to find any other workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove the hidden view from its superview. Then it will not appear on the screenshot.

```
[hiddenView removeFromSuperview];
```

EDIT:

If you don't know what subviews are hidden you can check it. The following code will remove all hidden subviews from a view and add them back.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UIView *subView, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return subView.hidden;
}];

NSArray *hiddenViews = [[myView subviews] filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

for (UIView *subView in hiddenViews) {
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}

//take your screenshot here

for (UIView *subView in hiddenViews) {
    [myView addSubview:subView];
}
```

EDIT2: As Duncan C pointed out, **this will not work for nested subviews**. You would need a recursive method for this.

Comment: There's a few reasons.  The two main ones are (1) The hidden items are other items that I still need, which is why I haven't removed them.  (They will be displayed later.)  (2)  My method, which animates away a view, is simply passed a view to animate away.  It is intended to work on any view in the app, and does not know anything about what is displayed on the view it is passed.  I shouldn't have to write custom code for every different view that this animation method is called on.

Comment: The code above might not preserve layer ordering. If an invisible view is between 2 other views that are visible, it won't get placed back in the right position. Another problem is that it won't deal with invisible subviews. If a top-level subview contains subviews or sub-sub views that are hidden, they won't get removed. The code would have to be a whole lot more sophisticated to do a full tree search of all the views and subviews in a view hierarchy, removing all the hidden views, and then putting them back into their proper subview, and in the right order.

Comment: @DuncanC Good point. As I would not care that much about layer ordering for invisible views (you can bring any subview to front when you unhide it), the second problem is bigger. It will not work for nested subviews.

Comment: Right - the question is, is there a way to either (1) have Core Graphics not see the hidden items, or (2) get a screenshot by some other method than Core Graphics?  I should not modify the view that's passed to me, as I have no knowledge of its makeup or purpose.

Comment: @adam I frequently set up nibs where I have items hidden and I just use an outlet to un-hide them when I want them to appear. I manipulate the hidden flag and my code doesn't worry (or know anything about) view ordering. That's good, because I can change layout in the nib file and the code still works.

Comment: @adam part 2: If you don't preserve view ordering, then the view hierarchy will be changed after taking a screenshot, and you will need to add additional logic to your code in order to return the view hierarchy to its original state. The OP's stated desire was for a screenshot routine that would work for any screen, and leave it in the same state once it was done. Both view ordering and view nesting are important and problematic to preserve.